# Page showing unnecessary spaces

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I am working on a CSS tab design page and this is how it looks like:

[image]

This is it's code (test2.php):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml2/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ajaxtabs.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ajaxtabs.js">

</script>

</head>

<body>
<?php
$page = isset($_GET['test2']) ? $_GET['test2'] : "" ;
?>

<ul id="countrytabs" class="shadetabs" style="clear:both">
<!--<li><a href="#" rel="#default" class="selected">Tab 1</a></li>-->
<li><a href="admin/add-client.php" rel="countrycontainer">Client</a></li>
<li><a href="admin/add-vendor.php" rel="countrycontainer">Vendor</a></li>
<!--<li><a href="admin/add-client.php" rel="#iframe">Tab 4</a></li>-->
</ul>

<div id="countrydivcontainer" style="border:1px solid gray; width:100%; height:100%; margin-bottom: 1em; padding: 10px; clear:both;">
<p>This is some default tab content, embedded directly inside this space and not via Ajax. It can be shown when no tabs are automatically selected, or associated with a certain tab, in this case, the first tab.</p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

var countries=new ddajaxtabs("countrytabs", "countrydivcontainer")
countries.setpersist(true)
countries.setselectedClassTarget("link") //"link" or "linkparent"
countries.init()

</script>

<hr />

</body>
</html>
```

But once I put this code inside a `<div>` in another code that calls upon it, it displays unnecessary space.

[image]

Here's my code for that (index.php):

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>ISYS</title>
<link href="../css/main-style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="../js/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/addfunction.js"></script>
<script src="../js/editfunction.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var width = 700;
    var height = 600;
    var left = parseInt((screen.availWidth/2) - (width/2));
    var top = parseInt((screen.availHeight/2) - (height/2));
    var windowFeatures = "width=" + width + ",height=" + height +   
        ",status,resizable,left=" + left + ",top=" + top + 
        "screenX=" + left + ",screenY=" + top + ",scrollbars=yes";
</script>
<script>
(function(document) {
    'use strict';

    var LightTableFilter = (function(Arr) {

        var _input;

        function _onInputEvent(e) {
            _input = e.target;
            var tables = document.getElementsByClassName(_input.getAttribute('data-table'));
            Arr.forEach.call(tables, function(table) {
                Arr.forEach.call(table.tBodies, function(tbody) {
                    Arr.forEach.call(tbody.rows, _filter);
                });
            });
        }

        function _filter(row) {
            var text = row.textContent.toLowerCase(), val = _input.value.toLowerCase();
            row.style.display = text.indexOf(val) === -1 ? 'none' : 'table-row';
        }

        return {
            init: function() {
                var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('light-table-filter');
                Arr.forEach.call(inputs, function(input) {
                    input.oninput = _onInputEvent;
                });
            }
        };
    })(Array.prototype);

    document.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {
        if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
            LightTableFilter.init();
        }
    });

})(document);
</script>
</head>

<body>
<?php
require("../dbconnect.php");
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : "test2" ;
?>
<div class="container">
  <div class="header"><img src="../images/CTILOGO.jpg" width="20%" height="90" style="background-color: #8090AB; display:inline;" />
  <a href="../logout.php"><img src="../images/logout.png" class="headermenu" style=" display:inline;" /></a>
  <a href="#home"><img src="../images/home.png" class="headermenu" style=" display:inline;" /></a>
  <a href="javascript:changePassword()" title="Change Password"><img src="../images/user.png" class="headermenu" style=" display:inline;" /></a>
    <!-- end .header --></div>
  <div class="sidebar1" id="link_ul">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="index.php?page=client">Client</a></li>
      <li><a href="index.php?page=vendor">Vendor</a></li>
      <li><a href="index.php?page=product">Product</a></li>
      <li><a href="index.php?page=user">Users</a></li>
      <li><a href="index.php?page=test2">test</a></li>
    </ul>
    <script>
                /*for active link*/
                    (function(){
                        $('#link_ul a').bind('click', function(e){
                            var me=$(this);
                            var as = $('#link').find('a');

                            as.removeClass('current');
                            me.addClass('current');
                        });

                    }());
    </script>
    <!-- end .sidebar1 --></div>
  <div class="content">
    <?php
        include(''.$page.'.php');
    ?>
    <!-- end .content --></div>
  <div class="footer">
    <p></p>
    <!-- end .footer --></div>
  <!-- end .container --></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want the `index.php` to look like the tabs in `test2.php`. I haven't change anything in the CSS part and everything's working fine except it's display. I am not sure where in the code's wrong. I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: Most likely is that your main-style.css is applying padding to an element, probably an li, or an a, which is affecting ALL instances of that element. Are you familiar with using inspector tools in the browser?

Comment: Sorry, what unnecessary spaces? I don't see any differences between your screen shots, except for the font.

Answer (score 0):

**Reset the CSS**. Maybe browser adds some unwanted padding or margin. put this code at the top of your css

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```